# Wrong decimal round to first 2 digits of amounts in python 3.7 and Django

Tags: python, django, decimal, rounding

Let there be 3 Django fields:

```py
    INPUT   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    RESULT  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    RATE    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5, default=1)
```

`RATE` is always `Decimal('1.00000')`.

I want to have `RESULT = INPUT * RATE` and since the source is either from database, either from APIs, I use:

```
RESULT = Decimal(INPUT) * Decimal(RATE)
```

I do not know why, but in some cases (≈ 2%) I end with the numbers you see in the following table. There is a round to the first 2 digits.

**Do you know what could cause that? I do not see anything in the code that could do that and I am clueless.** Both columns should be equal.

```sh
  RESULT    INPUT    
 610.000    609.000 
3700.000    3743.520
1200.000    1159.000
 570.000    573.300
  61.000    61.470
1300.000    1321.550
  44.000    43.730
 130.000    125.770
  18.000    18.500
 100.000    99.590
  41.000    40.650
  95.000    94.880
  19.000    18.710
  36.000    35.640
 120.000    118.800
  12.000    12.290
  11.000    11.260
   1.000    1.030
 160.000    155.970
 190.000    186.850
  51.000    50.770
 130.000    128.150
  12.000    12.290
  11.000    11.260
  25.000    24.940
  24.000    23.640
```

Comment: Are the results already wrong before they are saved into your database? Or are they only wrong when you retrieve them from the database?

Comment: @yagus I can only see the results and in local environment I cannot reproduce the error, same input produce good results. So, I cannot answer your question

Comment: If a SQLite database is used to store the data, that might cause issues. SQLite cannot represent the Decimal data type correctly.

Comment: There is a Postgre SQL database who store the data. I strongly suspect that too, but I cannot confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the cause is the decimal context precision:

`getcontext().prec = 2`

Somewhere in the code, it was set, and never reset. Here is what happens when the precision is 2:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext()
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[InvalidOperation, Inexact, FloatOperation, Rounded], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])

>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 2
>>> decimal.getcontext()
Context(prec=2, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[InvalidOperation, Inexact, FloatOperation, Rounded], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])

>>> Decimal(3.21)
Decimal('3.20999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375')
>>> Decimal(3.21) * Decimal(1)
Decimal('3.2')

>>> Decimal(58341)
Decimal('58341')
>>> Decimal(58341) * Decimal(1)
Decimal('5.8E+4')
```